# Android emulator can not connect web cam

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, webcam

When I try to connect my HP web cam in emulator, I am getting

> Unfortunately camera has stopped.

error in emulator when I run camera app provided in emulator.

And  I get following error in Android studio.

> emulator: WARNING: _get_pixel_format_descriptor: Pixel format P207 is unknown
>   emulator: ERROR: _camera_client_query_start: No conversion exist between P207 and NV21 (or RGB32) pixel formats

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64 Bit. *lsusb*  command gives following output.

Bus 002 Device 005: ID 093a:2460 Pixart Imaging, Inc. Q-TEC WEBCAM 100.

And my config.ini file is as follows.

```
avd.ini.encoding=UTF-8
AvdId=Nexus_5_API_23_x86
abi.type=x86
avd.ini.displayname=Nexus 5 API 23 x86
disk.dataPartition.size=200M
hw.accelerometer=yes
hw.audioInput=yes
hw.battery=yes
hw.camera.back=webcam0
hw.camera.front=emulated
hw.cpu.arch=x86
hw.dPad=no
hw.device.hash2=MD5:2fa0e16c8cceb7d385183284107c0c88
hw.device.manufacturer=Google
hw.device.name=Nexus 5
hw.gps=yes
hw.gpu.enabled=yes
hw.keyboard=yes
hw.lcd.density=480
hw.mainKeys=no
hw.ramSize=1536
hw.sdCard=yes
hw.sensors.orientation=yes
hw.sensors.proximity=yes
hw.trackBall=no
image.sysdir.1=system-images/android-23/google_apis/x86/
runtime.network.latency=none
runtime.network.speed=full
runtime.scalefactor=auto
sdcard.path=/home/user/.android/avd/Nexus_5_API_23_x86.avd/sdcard.img
skin.dynamic=yes
skin.name=nexus_5
skin.path=/home/user/android-studio/plugins/android/lib/device-art resources/nexus_5
snapshot.present=no
tag.display=Google APIs
tag.id=google_apis
vm.heapSize=64
```

Any one can help me to solve this problem?

Comment: is your webcam working in other applications?

Comment: Yes. It works fine in Cheese.

Comment: According to the error message, your webcam is using P207 (PAC207) encoding format and Android doesn't know how to convert this to NV21 encoding. Unfortunately I have no idea how you can solve this problem. Maybe you are able to somehow change the encoding format of your webcam?